# Open text file does not auto throw error when error occurs

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, throw

Do not throw error at run-time error occurs؟

for example  dose not exist `$errorMsg` for `fwrite($logFile,$errorMsg);`

or dose not exist `dirname(__FILE__).'\a\logError.txt`

in this code No run `er()` and no run `cache`???

and php default message will be displayed!

```
function er()
{
    echo "error.....";
}

try
{
        set_exception_handler('er');


        $logFile=fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'\a\logError.txt','w');        
        fwrite($logFile,$errorMsg);
        fclose($logFile);

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "catch";   
}   


Warning: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\HidariGold\a\logError.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\HidariGold\test.php on line 35

Notice: Undefined variable: errorMsg in C:\xampp\htdocs\HidariGold\test.php on line 36

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\HidariGold\test.php on line 36

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\HidariGold\test.php on line 37
```

So what is the benefit of `try{}catch{}`??????????

Comment: lol what? your question does not make sense...

Comment: i want to show my message show when error